# "No such file or directory" when importing local file into docker container using docker exec

Tags: mongodb, bash, docker

When running a shell command in docker exec with a local file as an argument, it fails with

**-bash:  docker/mongo.archive: No such file or directory**

```sh
$ docker exec -i 4cb4a63af40c sh -c 'mongorestore --archive' < 'docker/mongo.archive'
-bash:  docker/mongo.archive: No such file or directory
```

However, the file clearly exists at the given location:

```sh
$ ls docker/mongo.archive 
docker/mongo.archive
```

I remember using the exact same command and it worked. Also, I tried calling the command from within its directory (./docker) as well as from outside, using relative paths. Using the absolute path fails as well. Any ideas?

*Remark: 4cb4a63af40c is a mongodb container.*

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the quotes

```
docker exec -i 4cb4a63af40c sh -c 'mongorestore --archive < docker/mongo.archive'
```